# Ionic Facebook Authentication Redirection Problem

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I followed this tutorial step by step https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/ionic-facebook-login

The issue I’m having is that after the login, my app is not redirecting to the page I need it to. No error on the console when testing this on an emulated Pixel 2 device running Android 9 . Here’s the code for handling the authentication:

```
const permissions = ['public_profile', 'email'];

await this.facebook.login(permissions).then(response => {
    this.uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    this.facebook.api('/me?fields=name,email', permissions)
    .then(user => {
    user.picture = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + userId + 
    '/picture?type=large';
    this.dataService.getUser(this.uid).subscribe((data) => {
      if (data.data() !== undefined) {
        if (data.data().isNew) {
          this.zone.run(() => {
            this.router.navigate(['/profile']);
          });
        } else {
          this.zone.run(() => {
            this.router.navigate(['/home']);
          });
        }
      } else {
        this.dataService.addUser(....)}).then(() => {
          this.zone.run(() => {
            this.router.navigate(['/profile']);
        });
       }
     });
    });
```

I expect that after login success the app is redirected correctly using the router angular component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem cause

I figured the problem was related to my Angular Fire Auth Observable:

```
this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
              console.log('user state:', user);
              if (user) {
                this.fireUser = user;
                this.deviceStorage.set('uid', user.uid);
                this.dataService.userNewListener(user.uid);
              } else {
                    this.deviceStorage.set('uid', '');
                    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
              }
});
```

Since I'm using a native solution (facebook cordova plugin) that observable doesn't change, since it was redirecting me back to login.

## Solution

The solution was that after I successfully perform the login using the plugin, I could use the response access token as a credential to proceed and sign in with it using AngularFire:

```
this.facebook.login(permissions).then(response => {

    const facebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(response.authResponse.accessToken);
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(facebookCredential).then(() => {
              console.log('navigating profile');
              this.router.navigate(['/profile']);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by unravelling the code.

### Check the logs

You can use Chrome to see the output of whats happening and debug it:

[Using Chrome DevTools - Android Development - Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/android#using-chrome-devtools)

### Put some logging in there

Put some console.logs in the code like:

```
  if (data.data() !== undefined) {
    if (data.data().isNew) {
      this.zone.run(() => {
        console.log("routing to profile");
        this.router.navigate(['/profile']);
      });
    } else {
      this.zone.run(() => {
        console.log("routing to home");
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      });
    }
  } else {
    this.dataService.addUser(....)}).then(() => {
      this.zone.run(() => {
        console.log("adduser - routing to profile");
        this.router.navigate(['/profile']);
    });
  }
```

### Does the tutorial itself work?

Strip out your Firebase `dataService` calls and see if its getting to that point.

### Do you need the zone?

I think this was something that was sprinkled into the code for the beta of Ionic4 but mostly it's been resolved. I don't fully understand what it is but maybe you are following an out of date Firebase tutorial.

Comment: I removed the logs from the provided code to try to ease the reading of it. Chrome console when testing on emulated device shows the intended output, but still the router navigation is not working (in or outside of angular zone). No errors, just not navigating to the page I need it to :/

Comment: have you logged out the router to see if its there? `console.log({router: this.router});`

Comment: It is there, I have a bunch of other functions in that service that uses the router to navigate to different pages throughout the app. It is in the service's constructor.