# facebook login does not recieve response, no Error shown

Tags: angularjs, facebook, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

When i try to login to my app through facebook, it does not show me whether it was successful or unsuccessful.

Already tried going onto developer.facebook to enter my Hash and App ID Properly.
reinstalled cordova-plugin-facebook4
removed and added back android in ionic platforms

```
  this.fb.login(['email', 'public_profile']).then((response: 
      FacebookLoginResponse) => {
      this.provider = 'facebook'
      this.providerId = response.authResponse.userID
      this.token = response.authResponse.accessToken
      this.showAlert(this.token,this.providerId)
  })
```

expected Alert to be shown with token displayed whether undefined or not, but the actual output does not show

Comment: You should check what the response actually contains - it might be an error message, instead of the data you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking this with Chrome Console using a real device/emulator? Cordova plugins won't work when testing using `ionic serve`on Laptops/PCs.

I would suggest checking if there's an error coming back (add a catch) from the call. Add logs throughout your authentication code flow and check for outputs at every step.

Follow this tutorial: [Ionic Facebook Auth Tutorial](https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/ionic-facebook-login)

If you follow every step described you should be good to go.

I had an issue with this plugin a while back but I was getting the response back, problem I was having was related to redirection. I suggest you check my question's answer if it helps:

[Ionic Facebook Authentication Redirection Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56918466/ionic-facebook-authentication-redirection-problem/56939747#56939747)